# 'find-tag' Cannot Locate Emacs Source

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

I've been working through [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html) and have run into an issue on an exercise in section 4.6. The exercise states `Using find-tag, find the source for the copy-to-buffer function.` However, when using find-tag on my Mac installation of Emacs 24.2, it is unable to find the tag for the `copy-to-buffer` function. I have already created a tags file in the Emacs `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.2/lisp` directory, and `find-tag` is able to find many functions within this directory, but not `copy-to-buffer`. Any thoughts?

Comment: One thing puzzles me. You told us that your emacs installation is `24.2` but you are looking in the folder `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.3/lisp` for emacs `24.3`.

Comment: Apologies, 'twas a typo.

Comment: And you have the full sources, including `simple.el`? Maybe check this file for corruption?

Comment: For me it works (24.3.1 ubuntu). To diagnose the problem you can directly search the TAGS file for `copy-to-buffer`. If it is not in there it is a problem of `etags` and not of `emacs`. `copy-to-buffer` is in `simple.el`. Maybe, you have a directory with mixed sources `.el` and `.el.gz` and you did create the TAGS file only for one kind. The key-stroke `C-h f` shows the help for `copy-to-buffer`. Look whether this help includes a link to the elisp sources. If this link is missing then it might be that you only have the byte-compiled version `simple.elc`. `simple.el` should always be loaded.